# JMeter - How to Extract and Verify specific element and contents from Response Data

Tags: jmeter

From my Response Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PERSON>
  <NAME>Harry</NAME>
  <AGE>24</AGE>  
  <REMARKS></REMARKS>
  <DETAILS>
    <GENDER>MALE</GENDER>    
    <EYE_COLOR>BLUE</EYE_COLOR>
  </DETAILS>  
</PERSON>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PERSON>
  <NAME>Andrew</NAME>
  <AGE>4</AGE>  
  <REMARKS></REMARKS>
  <DETAILS>
    <GENDER>MALE</GENDER>    
    <EYE_COLOR>GREEN</EYE_COLOR>
  </DETAILS>
  <DETAILS>
    <WEIGHT>85KG</WEIGHT>    
    <HEIGHT>173CM</HEIGHT>
  </DETAILS>  
</PERSON>
```

..... and so on

I wish to Extract the whole of the 2nd Sequence and Verify its contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PERSON>
  <NAME>Andrew</NAME>
  <AGE>4</AGE>  
  <REMARKS></REMARKS>
  <DETAILS>
    <GENDER>MALE</GENDER>    
    <EYE_COLOR>GREEN</COLOR>
  </DETAILS>
  <DETAILS>
    <WEIGHT>85KG</WEIGHT>    
    <HEIGHT>173CM</HEIGHT>
  </DETAILS>  
</PERSON>
```

This Response can be very large, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the available post processor like "[CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)",Boundary Extractor,[Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) or JSR223 etc. All of them will help you to get the required data in a variable/s

But, if you need to just validate the response then you can use "Assertion" to check the response contains the required values or not.

I have used your example and getting the response and only validating the 2nd sequence as shown below:-

[image]
I have just copied your second sequence code and used "Add from Clipboard" option to put assertion. You can modify this as per your need.

Assertion consumes a lot of memory and should be avoided in load test.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `2ndPerson`
   - Regular Expression: `<PERSON>[\s\S]*?<\/PERSON>`
   - Template: `$1$`
   - Match No: `2`

     [image: JMeter Regular Expression]
3. Add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) as a child of the request
4. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable -> `2ndPerson_g0`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Pattern:

     ```
     <PERSON>
       <NAME>Andrew</NAME>
       <AGE>4</AGE>  
       <REMARKS></REMARKS>
       <DETAILS>
         <GENDER>MALE</GENDER>    
         <EYE_COLOR>GREEN</EYE_COLOR>
       </DETAILS>
       <DETAILS>
         <WEIGHT>85KG</WEIGHT>    
         <HEIGHT>173CM</HEIGHT>
       </DETAILS>  
     </PERSON>
     ```

     [image: JMeter Response Assertion]

Demo of Regular Expression:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Demo]